# Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.oracleucp.s-s-l-context.provider' to java.security.Provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

During Spring 2 to 3 migration I face this issue.
Only reproducible with SpringBoot 3, SpringBoot 2.7.14 is OK

### Dependencies

Spring Boot 3.1.2

Java 17

ojdbc11 21.9.0.0

ons 21.9.0.0

ucp 21.9.0.0

Same result with oracle-spring-boot-starter-ucp v3.1.0

### LOG

```
org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindException: Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.oracleucp.s-s-l-context.provider' to java.security.Provider
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.handleBindError(Binder.java:392) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:352) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:478) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ValueObjectBinder$ConstructorParameter.bind(ValueObjectBinder.java:318) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.ValueObjectBinder.bind(ValueObjectBinder.java:76) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:482) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:596) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:582) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:480) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:419) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:348) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$4(Binder.java:478) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:99) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder.bind(JavaBeanBinder.java:63) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.lambda$bindDataObject$5(Binder.java:482) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withIncreasedDepth(Binder.java:596) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder$Context.withDataObject(Binder.java:582) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindDataObject(Binder.java:480) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bindObject(Binder.java:419) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:348) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:337) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:267) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.Binder.bind(Binder.java:254) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBinder.java:94) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.bind(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:96) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor.java:79) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:419) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1762) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
at 


***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to bind properties under 'spring.datasource.oracleucp.s-s-l-context.provider' to java.security.Provider:

    Reason: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.security.Provider.<init>()

Action:

Update your application's configuration
```

Comment: can you update the question with `application.yml` file ?